# where should I place the count variable?

Tags: java, recursion

Write a recursive method that counts the number of creatures on a grid. A creature is defined as a contiguous collection of 1's (connected horizontally and vertically). I managed to approach the connection code, but I am stuck at where should I place the count variable 
for example:
if the input was

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

the output should be

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 2 2 2 0
3 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

The code:

```
public static void clearpic(int[][] a, int row, int col, int SIZE) {
    if ((0 <= row) && (row < SIZE) && (0 <= col) && (col < SIZE) && a[row][col] == 1) {
        a[row][col] = count;
        clearpic(a, row + 1, col, SIZE);
        clearpic(a, row, col + 1, SIZE);
        clearpic(a, row - 1, col, SIZE);
        clearpic(a, row, col - 1, SIZE);
    }
}

public static void print(int[][] a, int r, int c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            clearpic(a, i, j, a.length);
        }
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: public static void clearpic(int[][] a, int row, int col, int SIZE)
    {
        
    if ((0 <= row) && (row < SIZE) && (0 <= col) && (col < SIZE) && a[row][col] == 1) 
     {
      
      
      a[row][col]=count;
      clearpic (a,row+1,col, SIZE);
      clearpic (a,row,col+1, SIZE);

      clearpic (a,row-1,col, SIZE);
      clearpic (a,row,col-1, SIZE);
    }
    
    
    }

Comment: @eran here is the code that I have reached so far..the problem is count++ is incrementing each row by row and it's not incrementing by the values of ones which does not work for all types of inputs. I tried to sort this problem out but I got into compiler errors!!!!!

Comment: Is this question that hard that everybody just flew away?!!! pffffff

Comment: It's really unclear what this is trying to achieve.  But I think what you want to do is to pass `count` as a parameter to `clearpic`.

Comment: @DavidWallace the code should count the number of ones that are connected together vertically or horizontally as a one group..then the output  should illustrate the total number of groups..and display the array as the example shown above

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the count as a formal parameter to the recursive function.

```
public static void clearpic(int[][] a, int row, int col, int SIZE, int count) {
    if ((0 <= row) && (row < SIZE) && (0 <= col) && (col < SIZE) && a[row][col] == 1) {
        a[row][col] = count;
        clearpic(a, row + 1, col, SIZE, count);
        clearpic(a, row, col + 1, SIZE, count);
        clearpic(a, row - 1, col, SIZE, count);
        clearpic(a, row, col - 1, SIZE, count);
    }
}
```

The following code should be enough to satisfy the test case you have mentioned.

```
public static void print(int[][] a, int r, int c) {
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            clearpic(a, i, j, a.length, count);
        }
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't add much to what I did previously since I have used the count as a variable of type public static int. the problem is if my input was 
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
it prints 00000 02220 000000 000000 000000

Comment: while the ones should stay the same and not be inverted to two's so what my code is doing now is that it is replacing the ones with index of the row it is at @TanmayPatil

Comment: Your problem is that when `count` is 1, `clearpic` doesn't change anything.  Maybe you should either start `count` at 2, or use something other than 1 in the array's initial state.

Comment: @DavidWallace what I am thinking of right now is that count should actually start at 1 since I want it to marks the first group of ones as a one, and then increment the count value by 1 so that the second group found of ones is replaced by 2 and so on. My question is how to distinguish between the ones I have marked already and the ones that I haven't marked...and where can the count variable be placed in order to give the correct number of groups?

Comment: So start by changing every 1 in the array to -1.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm not sure if I am getting what u mean..u mean that I decrement instead of incrementing?